# Transfer a list of objects with properties from a C# Controller to a JavaScript function in a View

Tags: javascript, c#, json, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I'm having a hard time finding a solution for my issue and it doesn't help that I'm still a newbie.

I'm having trouble transferring a list of objects from one of my controllers to the main view of my website.

Class of the objects:

```
public class Session_Details
    {
        public string SessionID { get; set; }
        public string Product { get; set; }
        public string SessionSetup { get; set; }
        public string BoardNumber { get; set; }
        public string JobID { get; set; }
        public string Tester { get; set; }
        public string Operator { get; set; }
        public Session_Details(string sessionID, string product, string sessionSetup, string boardNumber, string jobID, string tester, string operatoR)
        {
            SessionID = sessionID;
            Product = product;
            SessionSetup = sessionSetup;
            BoardNumber = boardNumber;
            JobID = jobID;
            Tester = tester;
            Operator = operatoR;
        }
    }
```

How the objects are created:

```
public List<Session_Details> Results = new List<Session_Details>();

public List<Session_Details> LabQuery()
        {
            using (SqlConnection serverConn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
            {
                SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(QueryString,serverConn);
                serverConn.Open();
                SqlDataReader reader= sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();
                try
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        Results.Add(new Session_Details(reader[0].ToString(), reader[1].ToString(), reader[7].ToString(), reader[3].ToString(), reader[4].ToString(), reader[5].ToString(), reader[6].ToString()));
                    }

                    
                }
                finally
                {
                    reader.Close();
                }
            }
            return Results;
        }
```

My current way of passing the data through is via ViewBag like so:

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            //serializer is an instance of System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.
            ViewBag.RunningTests = serializer.Serialize(LabDashboard.LabQuery());
            
            return View();
        }
```

The data passes through just fine, but whenever I try to iterate through the objects via JS, the function immediately stops once it tries to set a var equal to ViewBag.RunningTests.

Things I have tried:

- setting var temp = '@ViewBag.RunningTests';
- setting var temp = @ViewBag.RunningTests;
- setting var temp = '@ViewBag.RunningTests[0]';
- setting var temp = @ViewBag.RunningTests[0];
- using a JSON serializer instead
- I did try to set var temp = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.RunningTests)), but it didn't work.

My ultimate goal is to iterate through these objects in JS and sort them into different "folders" in the View depending on what the object's Session_Details.Tester value is. If this can be done server side instead, that would be great as well. Any help is appreciated!!

Specifics:
.NET Framework 4.8
MVC 5.2.9
Razor 3.2.9
Visual Studio Professional 2022 v17.6.5

Edit:
This is the JS function that is supposed to iterate through the list:

```
function Sort() {
        for (var i = 0; i < @ViewBag.RunningTests.Length; i++)
        {
            var temp = Object.keys(@ViewBag.RunningTests);
            if (temp.includes('CCC-PAR')) {
                if (temp.includes('CCC-PAR-1')) {

                }
                else if (temp.includes('CCC-PAR-2')) {

                }
            }
            else if (temp.includes('CCC-SWC')) {

            }
            else if (temp.includes('CCC-VNA')) {

            }
            else if (temp.includes('CCC-VNF')) {

            }
            else if (temp.includes('CCC-SNF')) {

            }
            else if (temp.includes('MCE-MST')) {

            }

        }

    }
```

The purpose of the function is to sort the information and place them where they need to be (have not implemented the latter yet).

Comment: This should be possible server-side. Can you include the code for your view? Also, unrelated to the question but are you aware of ORM tools like Entity Framework? It will make your life a lot easier when querying from the database

Comment: Never heard of such tools, but I'll definitely look into them. Thank you!  I'll edit my post shortly with the code snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a lot of opportunity to clean up your code, but I'll try to focus on the main question first. How do you render a C# object as a JavaScript object in a view? You had the right approach earlier on:

- Convert the object to a JSON string using either `JsonConvert.SerializeObject()` or `Json.Encode()`

  - I recommend Newtonsoft.Json's `JsonConvert.SerializeObject` when serializing anything more than a plain C# class with primitive values, as it provides a lot more options and customizability when serializing complex types
- Render the string in a Script section of the page using `Html.Raw()`

```
<script>
var tests = @Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ViewBag.RunningTests));
</script>
```

The JavaScript you've posted seems to be looking for *keys*, as if the 'tests' variable is a dictionary with the 'Tester' as the key for each entry. You're passing the tests as a list, not a dictionary, so the `temp.includes()` checks would always return false. I suspect you intend the code to be looking at the 'Tester' property of each test:

```js
function Sort() {
    // Simplify the for-loop
    for (const test of tests) {
        // Look at the 'Tester' property of the test
        if (test.Tester.startsWith('CCC-PAR')) {
            if (test.Tester.startsWith('CCC-PAR-1')) {

            } else if (test.Tester.startsWith('CCC-PAR-2')) {

            }
        } else if (test.Tester.startsWith('CCC-SWC')) {

        } else if (...) {

        }
    }
}
```

---

If I were implementing this, I would prefer to make use of the features offered by MVC where I can.

You have all the data available when you render the view. Considering this, I would make a 'Model' (the 'M' of MVC) to represent the data used by the view. The controller gets the data from the database, puts it in a model, and passes the model to the view. Try to avoid using 'ViewBag' - it's not strongly typed, so you get no guarantees at compile time if the key your view is using will actually be provided by the controller.

```cs
public class RunningTestsModel
{
    public List<Session_Details> RunningTests { get; init; }
}

public ActionResult Index()
{
    var runningTests = LabDashboard.LabQuery();
    var model = new RunningTestsModel
    {
        RunningTests = runningTests,
    };

    // Render the view, using the data provided in the model
    return View(model);
}
```

When you render your view, you can look at the data in the model:

```
// This attribute means the view REQUIRES a 'RunningTestsModel' instance
// in order to be displayed properly
@model YourWebsite.WhateverNamespaceYouChoose.RunningTestsModel

<div id='CCC-PAR-1-folder'>
@foreach (var test in Model.RunningTests.Where(t => t.Tester.StartsWith("CCC-PAR-1"))
{
    <p>@test.SessionId</p>
}
</div>

<div id='CCC-PAR-2-folder'>
@foreach (var test in Model.RunningTests.Where(t => t.Tester.StartsWith("CCC-PAR-2"))
{
    <p>@test.SessionId</p>
}
</div>
```

Hopefully this helps with your immediate problem. Once you get it working, I highly recommend you post it to the CodeReview partner site and ask for feedback on what could be improved. You'll get suggestions about adding an ORM, making your 'LabDashboard' class less stateful, and reducing the chains of if-else blocks.

Comment: Quick little update: I was able to condense all of my if statements (like 15 or so lol) to a single line of code. I also implemented the @model passthrough and Entity Data Model for querying the DB. Way easier that way. Thank you for your help!